# How to run an Ansible task from Python without any YAML

Tags: python, ansible

I would like to use Ansible modules in Python for simple file modification tasks to avoid re-implementing things like adding lines to a file, while not having to configure Ansible. This code should only run on localhost, using no inventory, vars, or YAML - just some Python code.

Here's an example module I'd like to run from Python:

```yaml
- name: 'Add foobar to myfile'
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: 'myfile'
    line: 'foobar'
```

And here's some pseudo code:

```py
task = {
    'name': 'Add line to file'
    'action': {
        'module': 'lineinfile',
        'args': 'path=myfile dest=foobar'
    }
}
result = TaskExecutor(task).execute()
print(result)
```

Is this possible? How can I make this work with Ansible >= 8.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes I think it is possible, you can use the `ansible_runner` library to run Ansible tasks from Python with it.

you may need to install the `ansible_runner` library using `pip` before you can use it and make sure that the `myfile` file exists in the current directory before running the code.

let me explain it more via  `ansible_runner` for you :

## On older versions :

```
import ansible_runner

task = {
    'name': 'Add line to file',
    'action': {
        'module': 'lineinfile',
        'args': 'path=myfile line=foobar'
    }
}
result = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='./', host_pattern='localhost', module_args=task['action']['args'], module_name=task['action']['module'])
print(result)
```

in this case I'm using the `ansible_runner.run()` function to execute the `lineinfile` module with the specified arguments and the `private_data_dir` argument specifies the path to the directory where Ansible should look for its configuration files (in this case, I'm using the current directory).
The `host_pattern` argument specifies that the task should run on the localhost
at the end the `module_name` argument specifies the name of the module to run.

## On latest version (Version 2.3.3)

Here's how you can modify the code to work with the latest version of `ansible_runner` in this time is version 2.3.3:

```
import ansible_runner

task = {
    'name': 'Add line to file',
    'action': {
        'module': 'lineinfile',
        'args': 'path=myfile line=foobar'
    }
}

result = ansible_runner.run(private_data_dir='./', host_pattern='localhost', module_args_str=task['action']['args'], module=task['action']['module'])

print(result)
```

In this updated code, I'm using the new `module` and `module_args_str` arguments instead of `module_name` and `module_args`, respectively. This should work with the latest version of `ansible_runner`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, works like I expected - thanks! Just had to change ansible_runner.run parameters and rename `module_name` to `module`, maybe this changed in latest ansible_runner==2.3.3?

Comment: Yes,In the latest version of `ansible_runner` ver 2.3.3, the `module_name` argument has been renamed to `module`, and the `module_args` argument has been replaced with `module_args_str`